# The parameter 'CustomerProduct' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq

I am generating a dynamic LINQ expression as follows -

```
{Customer => Customer.CustomerProducts.Any
    (CustomerProduct => 
        (
            (CustomerProduct.BoughtDate >= Convert(9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM)) And 
            (CustomerProduct.BoughtDate <= Convert(9/10/2017 12:00:00 AM))
        )
    )
}
```

However, it throws an error as

> The parameter 'CustomerProduct' was not bound in the specified LINQ to
>   Entities query expression

Not sure what's wrong in above generated linq query.

Any help on this, very much appreciated.

Comment: Please show running code and add the correct programming language tag.

Comment: Please show the code that generates the expression. Most likely `CustomerProduct` inside the body is different `ParameterExpression` **instance** than the lambda parameter (but with the same **name**)